# Why don't we bootstrap terminal state in n-step temporal difference prediction update equation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods, model-free-methods, pseudocode

In the algorithm below, when $\tau + n \geq T$, shouldn't the algorithm bootstrap with the value of the next state? For instance, when $T=5, \tau=3, \& \; n=2$, we don't bootstrap the sample return with $V_{(\tau+n)}$, i.e., $V_5$ or the terminal state.

[image: Text]

Also, on line 4, what do we mean by "**can take their index mod $n + 1$**"?

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of the terminal state is 0 by definition. There is no further reward to be obtained once you reach the terminal state.